# how to correct two host names in known_hosts

Tags: ssh, zsh, ssh-keys, known-hosts

I'm trying to use `ssh-keygen -R` to remove a host line. However, each time I attempt this I get a `zsh: no matches found:`. When I look at the known_hosts file the line I want to modify starts like this `[slsapp.com]:1234,[108.163.203.146]:1234 ssh-dss`. I've tried to modify with both host names, with no luck. I even tried `ssh-keygen -R [slsapp.com]:1234,[108.163.203.146]:1234`

I'd rather not vim in or modify directly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell interprets characters inside `[...]` as alternatives for *one* character. See this example:

```
$ touch afoo bfoo cfoo dfoo
$ print -l [ac]foo
afoo
cfoo
```

So, quote the hostname with single quotes to prevent the shell to interpret any special characters:

```
$ ssh-keygen -R '[slsapp.com]:1234'
```

Comment: Thanks! When I re-push through ssh I regenerate the known_host line, which is what was expected. Thanks again.